# Pyconfigini: ImportError: No module named lib.pyconfigini

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been looking for an ini parse with inheritance support such as Zend_Config_Ini, So I found pyconfigini (https://bitbucket.org/maascamp/pyconfigini)

I have the following project structure:

- app

  - __ init __.py
  - settings.py
- lib

  - __ init __.py
  - pyconfigini.py

I copied pyconfigini.py module source here(https://bitbucket.org/maascamp/pyconfigini) to lib/pyconfigini.py and In my setting module (app/setting.py) I coded:

```
import os
from lib.pyconfigini import parse_ini
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), '../');
APP_ENV = os.getenv('APP_ENV','development')
config = parse_ini(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,"config.ini")), APP_ENV)
print config.nome
```

However when I run it in command line I get this error

```
> python settings.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "settings.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lib.pyconfigini import parse_ini
ImportError: No module named lib.pyconfigini
```

Why I am getting this error? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're running

```
python setting.py
```

from `app/` directory (which at the moment of script start becomes `current working directory`) . Python looks for modules in directories that are listed in **PYTHONPATH** environment variable (you can get access to it from Python code via `sys.path` variable).

This list of directories contains standard `site-packages`, `dist-packages`, etc. directories and you `current working directory` - a directory, from which you're trying to run your script.

As you can see from the above information, `lib` package cannot be found as it doesn't exist in directories listed in `sys.path`.

So, I advice you to change entry point script location to you root directory, where `app` and `lib` packages are located.

But if you wan't to test `settings.py` module for some reason running it directly, you can define your PYTHONPATH manually, running your script e.g. such way:

```
PYTHONPATH="../lib" python ./settings.py
```

This will patch your PYTHONPATH with needed `lib` directory.

Another way to run your app is to put `lib` package inside `app/` directory.

Comment: Yes, that will work, because lib will be a package inside your PYTHONPATH

Comment: Do you think should I move lib to inside app or move setting.py one directory behind(project/setting.py| project/app | project/lib)? Any architecture advice? I am new to python and I am not sure what would be better.

Comment: I recommend you to read introduction to python packaging where recommended source tree is advised: http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko I think I'm also experiencing this problem. I'm getting a 'no module named lib' error. Do I need to move folders around or do I need to change the settings in my EPD? I've posted a question describing my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441293/importerror-no-module-named-lib-unable-to-import-pandas-numpy-scipy-matplot